# In what programming language are the android obb files coded in?

Tags: android

In what programming language are the android obb files coded in? Are they coded in native languages like C and C++ or in Java the same way apk files are coded?

Comment: does this help? http://blog.droidapks.net/install-apk-with-obb-data/

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for Android's [StorageManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html), an OBB (Opaque Binary Blob) contains a filesystem that contains resources. The filesystem in the OBB could contain anything, including code, images, audio files, video files, etc.

The "Opaque" part means that the way that it is encoded is meant as a proprietary "black box" - we're not meant to know exactly how it is encoded.

Answer (score 1):

OBB files are used for APK expansion, read more here https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

> Each expansion file you upload can be any format you choose (ZIP, PDF, MP4, etc.).
>
> Regardless of the file type, Google Play considers them opaque binary blobs and renames the files using the following scheme:
>
> [main|patch]...obb

They are usually a zip file (renamed to `.obb`) and then of course the zip can contain whatever the developer chooses.

You can also create encrypted `obb` files with the JOBB tool found here: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jobb.html